# MQ Connection in Linux os

Tags: c, linux, ibm-mq

I  wrote a C program to connect to message queue(Websphere MQ) and ran on Linux OS
On running ,the program returns 2012 reason code(MQRC_ENVIROMENT_ERROR) and mqconnection gets failed.
The same C program works completely fine on AIX OS(MQ Version: 7.5.0.2)
.
So do we need to make any setting specific to the Linux enviroment.(MQ VERSION      7.0.1.9) so the error gets resolved?.

Comment: Perhaps strace(1) could give yous some ideas.

Comment: Could be this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230205, but worth taking a look at the required kernel settings in general.

Comment: Thanks for the response .could  you please elaborate on kernel settings

Comment: Please post the details of how you built the program, that's the most likely problem if the same code works elsewhere.

Comment: this is how i am compiling the code

Comment: gcc -m64 -o mq mq.c -I/opt/mqm/inc -L/opt/mqm/lib64 -lmqic -Wl,-rpath=/opt/mqm/lib64

Comment: /* variables for MQCONN ******/
MQCHAR QMmgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH];
MQHCONN Hconn = 0;

MQLONG CompCode,Reason,OpenCompCode;
int counter=0;

QMmgrName[0] = '\0' ; /* set to null default QM */
strcpy(QMmgrName, QUEUEMANAGER );
strncpy(Queue,"PACMAN",MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);

MQCONN(QMmgrName,
&Hconn,
&CompCode,
&Reason);
if (CompCode != MQCC_OK)
{
printData( "get_org_hierarchy:MQCONN failed with CompCode:%d, Reason:%d [%s:%d]",CompCode,Reason, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
return (CompCode);
}

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the section in the [MQ Knowledge Center](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q040860_.htm) on RC 2012?

Here are 2 items that are probably applicable:

- The application is linked to the wrong libraries (threaded or nonthreaded).
- The MQBEGIN call was issued in an MQ MQI client environment.

Comment: I had went through mq knowledge centr but didnot understand what action has to be taken

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't post your code and makefile.

Comment: Source code of mqconnection
    
    /* variables for MQCONN *****/
    MQCHAR QMmgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH];
    MQHCONN Hconn = 0;
    
    MQLONG CompCode,Reason,OpenCompCode;
    int counter=0;
    
    QMmgrName[0] = '\0' ; /* set to null default QM */
    strcpy(QMmgrName, QUEUEMANAGER );
    strncpy(Queue,"PACMAN",MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);
    
    MQCONN(QMmgrName,
    &Hconn,
    &CompCode,
    &Reason);
    if (CompCode != MQCC_OK)
    {
    printData( "get_org_hierarchy:MQCONN failed with CompCode:%d, Reason:%d [%s:%d]",CompCode,Reason, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
    return (CompCode);
    }

Comment: Don't post the code in a comment - put it in your original question and use the code tag.  Also, put the makefile too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Reinstalled the mq in linux environment.MQ Version is 7.5.0 and the program will work as needed